# How to change theme font for Volcano Plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to wrangle a Volcano plot made with the `EnhancedVolcano` package to have all text in Arial font style. I tried to do so with this code:

```
a <- EnhancedVolcano(data.matrix,
  lab = rownames(data.matrix), x = "Log2.fold.change",
  y = "P.value", xlim = c(-2, 2), ylim = c(0, 6), xlab = bquote(~ Log[2] ~ "fold change"), 
  ylab = bquote(~ -Log[10] ~ italic(P)), axisLabSize = 12, 
  title = paste("NanoString -", data.name), subtitle = "", 
  labFace = "bold", pointSize = 2, labSize = 5, pCutoff = 10e-2, FCcutoff = 0.4, 
  gridlines.major = FALSE, gridlines.minor = FALSE, drawConnectors = TRUE, 
  widthConnectors = 0.2, colConnectors = "black", legendPosition = "none"
)

print(a)

EV_merge <- a + theme(text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"))

print(EV_merge)
```

The problem I'm having is the `element_text` command, which I thought would work since the plot is an object in `ggplot2`, seems to only work for the axis and title text, but the font of the labels for the specific genes seems to remain the same. What function should I be using in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The labels are nothing to do with `theme`. They are created by `geom_text_repel`, so they are part of a data layer. There doesn't seem to be an option to change the font family of the labels, but you can change it in situ after the plot is created.

Obviously, I don't have your data, but using the example from the help page and saving it as `EV_merge`, we have:

```r
EV_merge
```

[image]

To change the font face and family, we can do:

```r
EV_merge$layers[[4]]$aes_params$fontface <- 1
EV_merge$layers[[4]]$aes_params$family <- "sans"

EV_merge
```

[image]

Comment: As a follow-up question, how did you determine the corresponding layer to be EV_merge$layers[[4]]?

Comment: @JunLi you can do `sapply(EV_merge$layers, function(x) class(x$geom)[1])` to find which one is the text layer